# Software downloader downloading dozens of mb (almost) every day

Tags: 13.04, software-updater

Why does ubuntu's software updater download around 80 MB (almost) *every day*? Does it simply replace the original content constantly? It is not always downloading for the same application, but it still strikes me as too much.

Answer (score 0):

80 MB sounds little bit strange for me. Actually Software updater will update its cache by depending upon the setting you made. When it have updated the cache it will redownload it. as far as I know that will be around 19MB - 20 MB in my case.[image]